# How to Order Conditionally in Linq EF Core?

Tags: .net, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

How can I write OrderBy conditionally?
As you can see in both if and else condition entire linq is same only orderBy is different.
In first case I am ordering in ascending and in second case I am ordering in descending
How to combine both of these condition so that I can avoid redundancy of code?

Also I want to fetch filtered data from database so I don't want to store query in variable and apply orderBy later.

```cs
public IAsyncEnumerable<Dictionary> GetDictionaryData(int page,float limit,string? sort,string? name)
{  
    Func<EDMDbContextSQLServer, IAsyncEnumerable<Dictionary>>? query;      
    if(sort=="dictionary_name" || sort=="destination_dataset_name")
    {
        query = EF.CompileAsyncQuery((EDMDbContextSQLServer _dbContext)
                => _dbContext.DictionaryMasterUpdateInfo
                    .Include(dm => dm.DictionaryMaster)
                        .ThenInclude(dm => dm==null ? null : dm.SourceDataSetMaster)
                    .Include(dm => dm.DictionaryMaster)
                        .ThenInclude(dm => dm==null ? null : dm.DestinationDataSetMaster)
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .Select(x => new Dictionary
                    {
                        DictionaryId = x.DictionaryId,
                        DictionaryName = x.DictionaryMaster!.DictionaryName,
                        DestinationDatasetId = x.DictionaryMaster.DestinationDatasetId,
                        SourceDatasetId = x.DictionaryMaster.SourceDatasetId,
                        IsStandard = x.DictionaryMaster.IsStandard,
                        SourceDataSetName = x.DictionaryMaster.SourceDataSetMaster != null ? x.DictionaryMaster.SourceDataSetMaster.DataSetName : "",
                        DestinationDataSetName = x.DictionaryMaster.DestinationDataSetMaster == null ? "" : x.DictionaryMaster.DestinationDataSetMaster.DataSetName,
                    })
                    .OrderBy(x=>sort=="dictionary_name" ? x.DictionaryName : x.DestinationDataSetName)
                    .Skip((page - 1) * (int)limit)
                    .Take((int)limit));
    }
    else
    {              
        query = EF.CompileAsyncQuery((EDMDbContextSQLServer _dbContext)
                =>_dbContext.DictionaryMasterUpdateInfo
                    .Include(dm => dm.DictionaryMaster)
                        .ThenInclude(dm => dm==null ? null : dm.SourceDataSetMaster)
                    .Include(dm => dm.DictionaryMaster)
                        .ThenInclude(dm => dm==null ? null : dm.DestinationDataSetMaster)
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .Select(x => new Dictionary
                    {
                        DictionaryId = x.DictionaryId,
                        DictionaryName = x.DictionaryMaster!.DictionaryName,
                        DestinationDatasetId = x.DictionaryMaster.DestinationDatasetId,
                        SourceDatasetId = x.DictionaryMaster.SourceDatasetId,
                        IsStandard = x.DictionaryMaster.IsStandard,
                        SourceDataSetName = x.DictionaryMaster.SourceDataSetMaster != null ? x.DictionaryMaster.SourceDataSetMaster.DataSetName : "",
                        DestinationDataSetName = x.DictionaryMaster.DestinationDataSetMaster == null ? "" : x.DictionaryMaster.DestinationDataSetMaster.DataSetName,
                    })
                    .OrderByDescending(dm => dm.ModifiedOn!.Value.Date)
                    .ThenByDescending(dm => dm.ModifiedOn!.Value.TimeOfDay)
                    .ThenBy(x=>x.DictionaryName)
                    .Skip((page - 1) * (int)limit)
                    .Take((int)limit));
        


    }
    return query(_dbContext);
}
```

Comment: Why compiled query? You need at least 3 compiled queries. Also compiled query have no sense if you do not store and reuse it from static variable.

Comment: A compiled query in this case only adds overhead. Compiled queries don't generate faster SQL. They avoid the overhead of generating that SQL by providing a delegate that can be called instead. That delegate still generates the same SQL. The question's code doesn't reuse anything though, it rebuilds and re-compiles the same query over and over

Answer (score 1):

You don't need compiled query here and everything can be simplified.

1. `IQueryable` do not execute query until you call enumeration operator
2. `Include()` is ignored if you have `Select`
3. `AsNoTracking()` is not needed if you produce custom entity via `Select`
4. You do not have to check for null navigation properties, EF Core will handle this.
5. Better return `IQueryable`, then you can apply `CountAsync`, `ToArrayAsync`, `ToListAsync` ect.

```cs
public IQueryable<Dictionary> GetDictionaryData(int page, float limit, string? sort, string? name)
{  
    var query = _dbContext.DictionaryMasterUpdateInfo
        .Select(x => new Dictionary
        {
            DictionaryId = x.DictionaryId,
            DictionaryName = x.DictionaryMaster!.DictionaryName,
            DestinationDatasetId = x.DictionaryMaster.DestinationDatasetId,
            SourceDatasetId = x.DictionaryMaster.SourceDatasetId,
            IsStandard = x.DictionaryMaster.IsStandard,
            SourceDataSetName = x.DictionaryMaster.SourceDataSetMaster.DataSetName ?? "",
            DestinationDataSetName = x.DictionaryMaster.DestinationDataSetMaster.DataSetName ?? "",
        });

    switch (sort)
    {
        case "dictionary_name" : query = query.OrderBy(x => x.DictionaryName); break;
        case "destination_dataset_name" : query = query.OrderBy(x => x.DestinationDataSetName); break;
        default : query = query.OrderBy(x => x.DictionaryName)
                     .ThenByDescending(dm => dm.ModifiedOn!.Value.TimeOfDay); 
           break;
    }

    query = query
        .Skip((page - 1) * (int)limit)
        .Take((int)limit);

    return query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
something = EF.CompileAsyncQuery((EDMDbContextSQLServer _dbContext)
                =>_dbContext.DictionaryMasterUpdateInfo
                    .Include(dm => dm.DictionaryMaster)
                        .ThenInclude(dm => dm==null ? null : dm.SourceDataSetMaster)
                    .Include(dm => dm.DictionaryMaster)
                        .ThenInclude(dm => dm==null ? null : dm.DestinationDataSetMaster)
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .Select(x => new Dictionary
                    {
                        DictionaryId = x.DictionaryId,
                        DictionaryName = x.DictionaryMaster!.DictionaryName,
                        DestinationDatasetId = x.DictionaryMaster.DestinationDatasetId,
                        SourceDatasetId = x.DictionaryMaster.SourceDatasetId,
                        IsStandard = x.DictionaryMaster.IsStandard,
                        SourceDataSetName = x.DictionaryMaster.SourceDataSetMaster != null ? x.DictionaryMaster.SourceDataSetMaster.DataSetName : "",
                        DestinationDataSetName = x.DictionaryMaster.DestinationDataSetMaster == null ? "" : x.DictionaryMaster.DestinationDataSetMaster.DataSetName,
                    });
query = (sort=="dictionary_name" || sort=="destination_dataset_name") ?
(something..OrderBy(x=>sort=="dictionary_name" ? x.DictionaryName : x.DestinationDataSetName)
                    .Skip((page - 1) * (int)limit)
                    .Take((int)limit))) :
(something..OrderByDescending(dm => dm.ModifiedOn!.Value.Date)
                    .ThenByDescending(dm => dm.ModifiedOn!.Value.TimeOfDay)
                    .ThenBy(x=>x.DictionaryName)
                    .Skip((page - 1) * (int)limit)
                    .Take((int)limit)));
```